# Get value form Map in Java

Tags: java

I have Map in Java.
I would like to get myType form map and save it to variable.

For example:

```
Map<String,myType>
myType mt = ... ;
```

How can I do that? 
Many thanks!

Comment: [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you:

```
Map<String,myType> map = new HashMap<String,myType>();
map.put("str",new myType());
Set<Map.Entry<String,myType>> s = map.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,myType>> it = s.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry<String,myType> item = it.next();
myType mt = item.getKey();
```